# How to upload image in MERN web application with react-hook-form and multer

Tags: reactjs, forms, multer, react-hook-form, use-form

I am using react-hook-form for form submission and multer for storing images, but not able to store image.

```
  const onSubmitHandler = async (data) => {
    const { photo, ...others } = data;
    const image = photo[0];
    const newUser = { image, ...others };
    const res = await createHotel(newUser);
  };

return (
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitHandler)}>
          <div >
              <label>upload image</label>
              <input type="file" name="photo" {...register("photo")} />
         </div>
         <button  type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
)


on backend

router
  .route("/")
  .post(upload.single("image"), createHotel)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React, image is not uploading, getting filename is not defined error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136807/react-image-is-not-uploading-getting-filename-is-not-defined-error)

Comment: Getting this error ""Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buffer')"